# Combine Two Queries in one SUM Case

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two queries with exact same grouping but I dont seem to be able to combine them in a correct way.

Query1:

```
SELECT 
    WorkPeriods.Id AS Z_Number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(DATE, WorkPeriods.StartDate, 103)), 103) AS Z_Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Cash' THEN Payments.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Cash_Payments, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Cash' THEN 1 END) AS No_of_Tickets_Cash,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Credit Card' THEN Payments.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Credit_Card_Payments, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Credit Card' THEN 1 END) AS No_of_Tickets_Credit_Card
FROM 
    Payments, WorkPeriods
WHERE
    Payments.Date BETWEEN WorkPeriods.StartDate AND WorkPeriods.EndDate 
GROUP BY 
    WorkPeriods.Id, WorkPeriods.StartDate
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
    WorkPeriods.Id AS Z_Number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(DATE, WorkPeriods.StartDate, 103)), 103) AS Z_Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.CalculatePrice = 0 THEN Orders.Quantity * Orders.Price ELSE 0 END) AS Gifts_Amount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.CalculatePrice = 0 THEN Orders.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS No_of_Gift_Orders
FROM 
    Orders, WorkPeriods
WHERE 
    Orders.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN WorkPeriods.StartDate AND WorkPeriods.EndDate
GROUP BY 
    WorkPeriods.Id, WorkPeriods.StartDate
```

Any advice on how to continue? I have already tried merging them using all 3 tables and all sum-count conditions but the result I get is wrong. I need all results to appear on the same row. Attached are query results

[image: query1]

[image: query2]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Apologies SQl Server 2008

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can't just join them all in the one query, as you will get incorrect values as soon as you get multiple orders or payments in the same workperiod.

You could use the current queries as sub queries, and full join them to get the result. By using full join you get any results that are only on one table and not the other.

```
Select ISNULL(Pay.Z_Number, Ord.Z_Number) As Z_Number,
  ISNULL(Pay.Z_Date, Ord.Z_Date) as Z_Date,
  Pay.CashPayments,
  Pay.No_of_Tickets_Cash,
  Ord.Gifts_Amount
  --other fields as appropriate
FROM (
    --Query 1 here
    ) AS Pay
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    --Query 2 here
    ) as Ord ON Pay.Z_Number = Ord.Z_Number and Pay.Z_Date = Ord.Z_Date
```

Another way to do this, is to create one sub query that has the data from both payments and orders in it unioned together, and then sum the resulting list in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample query may be helpful

```
    SELECT 
MAIN_T.Z_Number
,MAIN_T.Z_Date
,T1.Cash_Payments
,T1.Credit_Card_Payments
,T1.No_of_Tickets_Cash
,T1.No_of_Tickets_Credit_Card
,T2.Gifts_Amount
,T2.No_of_Gift_Orders

FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
    WorkPeriods.Id AS Z_Number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(DATE, WorkPeriods.StartDate, 103)), 103) AS Z_Date
FROM 
    Payments, WorkPeriods
WHERE
    Payments.Date BETWEEN WorkPeriods.StartDate AND WorkPeriods.EndDate ) MAIN_T

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    WorkPeriods.Id AS Z_Number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(DATE, WorkPeriods.StartDate, 103)), 103) AS Z_Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Cash' THEN Payments.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Cash_Payments, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Cash' THEN 1 END) AS No_of_Tickets_Cash,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Credit Card' THEN Payments.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Credit_Card_Payments, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Payments.Name = 'Credit Card' THEN 1 END) AS No_of_Tickets_Credit_Card
FROM 
    Payments, WorkPeriods
WHERE
    Payments.Date BETWEEN WorkPeriods.StartDate AND WorkPeriods.EndDate 
GROUP BY 
    WorkPeriods.Id, WorkPeriods.StartDate) T1
    ON MAIN_T.Z_Number=T1.Z_Number AND MAIN_T.Z_Date=T1.Z_Date

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    WorkPeriods.Id AS Z_Number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(DATE, WorkPeriods.StartDate, 103)), 103) AS Z_Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.CalculatePrice = 0 THEN Orders.Quantity * Orders.Price ELSE 0 END) AS Gifts_Amount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.CalculatePrice = 0 THEN Orders.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS No_of_Gift_Orders
FROM 
    Orders, WorkPeriods
WHERE 
    Orders.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN WorkPeriods.StartDate AND WorkPeriods.EndDate
GROUP BY 
    WorkPeriods.Id, WorkPeriods.StartDate) T2
    ON MAIN_T.Z_Number=T2.Z_Number AND MAIN_T.Z_Date=T2.Z_Date
```